# Populating a form field from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

So I need to fill in a text field and a radio field from the database if the user decides they want to make changes to the form. This is a form that can be saved and edited later.

I am unsure if I ma doing this correctly, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the function to call the data from mysql:

```
function editForms($selectedForm) {
$UID_login = $_SESSION['UID_login'];
$form_data_query = "SELECT * FROM F1 WHERE uid='$UID_login' AND form_name='$selectedForm'";

if ($result = mysql_query($form_data_query)) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < 1; ++$j) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $F1Q1 = $row[3];
            $F1Q2 = $row[4]; 
        }
} else {
        echo .mysql_error();
}
}

if (isset($_GET['view'])){
$selectedForms = $_GET['view'];
editForms($selectedForms);
}
```

Here are the html data fields:

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                 Do you want to Add, Modify or Delete an eSetup item? *
                 </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="action" <?php if (isset($F1Q1) && $F1Q1=="add") echo "checked";?> value="add" >Add 
                    <input type="radio" name="action" <?php if (isset($F1Q1) && $F1Q1=="modify") echo "checked";?> value="modify" >Modify 
                    <input type="radio" name="action" <?php if (isset($F1Q1) && $F1Q1=="delete") echo "checked";?> value="delete" >Delete 
                    <span class="error"><?php echo $F1Q1Err;?></span>
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->                 
            <tr>
                <td>
                Please provide any details about what needs to be completed with this request.</td>
                <td><textarea name="comments" rows="4" cols="50" maxlength="1000" ><?php echo $F1Q2;?></textarea></td>                                  
                </tr>
```

I hope that this is enough for you guys to help. I am not really sure if I am doing this correctly. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by making this breathe a little `SELECT*FROM` to `SELECT * FROM` - it's just good practice.

Comment: Indeed, I have been trying to become more consistent with my style.

Comment: What were the results in your attempt with your code?

Comment: I am able to output the variables $F1Q1 and $F1Q2 above the form, however the problem lies when I try to place them into the form. I don't receive any errors.

Comment: Sorry, I examined your entire code and can't wrap my head around it. I wish I could have helped you, but in this case I can't. I do have one comment/question. You do have `<form>` in your HTML, right? Might be a silly question, but I needed to ask, since I don't see it in your posted code.

Comment: Haha yeah I do, but I think I figured out the problem. I changed $row to an array `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` and changed the php within the form itself to `<?php echo $row[3]?>`

Comment: Ah, that's great news! Glad to hear it.